# Handling dynamic text editing in an MFC CView

Tags: mfc, cedit

I have a class that implements OnDraw to draw text and images to a CView.  At certain times (ie onClick) I would like this text to be editable in place.  What would be the best way to implement this?

- Have the class have a CEdit object that I hide and show and draw over
  the top of my text.
- Handle key presses in the class and implement my
  own editing
- Have something external to the class control whether to show the edit box or my class
- Something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go with your first idea, create a CEdit box when you need some text editing. If you look at how a ListCtrl handles rename functionality it does exactly that.